# Where should one store application strings when localization isn't needed?

Tags: c#, .net

Should I use settings, store them as resources, load them into a Dictionary, or just hard-code them?

Or is there another, better way?

I've been hard-coding them for apps that don't need localization, but it seems like there might be a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, using resource files still works well. It gives the advantage of being able to use consistent text (error messages, warnings, notices, etc.) and allows you to modify text without rebuilding your app.

Comment: Without rebuilding your app -- As in resgen?

Answer (score 1):

I would store them in resources anyway.